# Calculte precision and recall for text mining result

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall

I am doing a project to find out the disease associated genes using text mining. I am using 1000 articles for this. I got around 129 gene names. The actual dataset contains around 1000 entries. Now I would like to calculate the precision and recall of my method. When i did the comparison, out of the 129 genes, 72 were found to be correct. So the 
precision = 72/129.
Is it correct?
Now how can I calculate the recall? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Wikipedia Article on Precision and Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall#Definition_.28classification_context.29) might help.
The definitions are:

```
Precision: tp / (tp+fp)
Recall: tp / (tp + fn)
```

Where `tp` are the true positives (genes which are associated with disease and you found them), `fp` are the false positives (genes you found but they actually aren't associated with the disease) and `fn` are the false negatives (genes which are actually associated with the disease but you didn't find them).

I am not quite sure what the numbers you have posted represent. Do you know the genes which are truly associated with the disease?

You have most likely computed the accuracy:

```
Accuracy = (tp + fp) / (Total Number)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I got it cleared last day, and I am posting the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that the articles that i am considering might not contain all the originally listed gene names since its a small dataset. So while calculating the recall, instead of considering the denominator as 1000, I can compare the original database of genes with the articles to find out how many of the originally associated genes are present in the literature. i.e., if there are 1000 associated genes, I will check out of 1000 how many are there in the dataset I am considering. If it is 300, i will set the denominator as 300 instead of 1000. That will give recall.